# Insert into NULL value Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

When i create this table using postgresql,

```
CREATE TABLE villeseo (
    ville_id bigserial primary key,
    ville varchar(50),
    cp integer,
        h1 text,
    h2 text,
    h31 text,
    h32 text,
    h33 text,
    h34 text,
    para1 text,
    para2 text,
    para3 text,
    para4 text,
        theme text,
    forme text
);
```

and then start to INSERT INTO as below with empty **h34** and **para4**

```
INSERT INTO "villeseo" (ville,cp,h1,h2,h31,h32,h33,h34,para1,para2,para3,para4,theme,forme)
VALUES 


("Antony",
 92160,
 "Cours particuliers à domicile à Antony",
 "Trouvez le professeur qui vous correspond !",
 "Antony, une ville au cœur du développement", 
 "Quel enseignement pour les étudiants d’Antony ?",
 "Un étudiant qualifié à Antony !",
 ,
 "La ville d’Antony située en Hauts-de-Seine en Ile-de-France est un véritable carrefour des...",
 ,
 "74%",
 "77%");
```

I end up with this **error syntax error at or near ","** and i can't figure out why.

[ERROR -> syntax error at or near ","](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhAuc.png)

Thanks for your help.

Leonard

Comment: values should be in single quotes. doubles are for identifiers, not for strings

Comment: You don't leave VALUE empty, if you want to insert NULL values then the value is set `NULL` like: `... VALUES ( 'a', NULL', 'b', ...)`

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Answer (score 0):

Change your statement to:

```
INSERT INTO "villeseo" (ville, cp, h1, h2, h31, h32, h33, h34, 
                       para1, para2, para3, para4, theme, forme )
VALUES ('Antony',
         92160,
        'Cours particuliers à domicile à Antony',
        'Trouvez le professeur qui vous correspond !',
        'Antony, une ville au cœur du développement', 
        'Quel enseignement pour les étudiants d’Antony ?',
        'Un étudiant qualifié à Antony !',
         NULL ,
         'La ville d’Antony située en Hauts-de-Seine en Ile-de-France est un véritable carrefour des...',
         NULL ,
         '74%',
         '77%');
```